# how RegEx can remain within the Widows 255 chars limit for filenames, if we want to use the pattern as a filename?

Tags: windows, character, filenames

Filenames in Windows are limited to 255 chars, so, if want to use a RegEx pattern as my filename, I will have to remain forcibly within this limit...

Now, is there any process/function (at its very end, say before %) for the 'expression engine' to count the total number/amount of characters it has used in the pattern  (with no outside programming but only within the pattern itself) ?

I tried scanning the web and even asking Bard and ChatGPT, but with now satisfying answers... :(